# Clustering/grouping objects based on value similarity and constraints on summed size

Tags: python, c#, algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

Consider having an array of items that have a size and a value. I need to write a method where I end up with minimal groups/clusters where all objects in a group must have similar values (as close as possible), while the sum of all sizes is between predefined min- and max- sumSize (ideally just over the min value).

```
#EXAMPLE

items = {
    # NAME, Value, Size
      ('A',    10,    3),
      ('B',    11,    1),
      ('C',    10,    7),
      ('D',    15,   11),
      ('E',    22,    5),
      ('F',    20,    7),
      ('G',    25,    1)};
minSumSize = 10;
maxSumSize = 100;

##SOLUTION: {'A','B', 'C'}, {'D'}, {'E', 'F', 'G'}
```

Ideally, there should be a minimal value deviation(aka group by the same value), but quite often items' size with the same value (e.g. A and C) don't sum up to the minimum size. There are no objects that are over the maximum size and items are non-splittable items. Bonus: If a group can be broken down further while still being over the minimum SumSize, then do that

What would be the most optimal approach/algorithm that I can base my code on?
I would love to get an idea which direction or method should I use. I honestly don't care in which programming language, as the logic would be the same everywhere.

**What I have tried so far:**

I haven't completed almost any of the methods I researched of fear I am going down a rabbit hole that is wrong, but some suggestions I found were:

- 1D k-means, DBscan or a variation of the 0/1 knapsack problem where the amount of knapsacks is undefined
- something based graph theory? Technically, this problem can be represented as a weighted undirected graph where the nodes carry the weights and the edges carry the value difference between 2 nodes. And then, ideally, remove all unneeded edges, so you end up with a bunch of sub-graphs(groups) that overall have a minimal sum of edges and the sum of the node weight is in the size constraints.
- A simpler brute-force strategy where you cluster first by value similarity using mean difference/standard difference deviation and then group by size constraints, but quite often you end up with edge cases where groups need to merge up or down, which is not ideal and lead to a pretty messy code solution with a lot of edge cases.

**UPDATE:**
I hope I can clear some stuff by adding a bit more context. When I created the premise, I added some of my bias and focused on grouping based on sum size. As much as that is important, it can be a bit arbitrary as the maximum sum size is 5x to 10x the minimum and each item size can be anywhere from 10% to 2x the minimum sum. I also wrote that the groups should be broken down to a minimum, but they don't have to be as long as they are in the range. My reasoning is that this would help with having similar values grouped together, but I might be wrong. They also don't need to have an equal amount of items, just items similar in value. The amount of elements and sum size don't need to be similar across groups.

On another hand, I should have also named Value -> Price, because the reason for grouping by similar value is that after all items are grouped together, a group value is chosen for the whole group by taking the highest valued item in the group, which would raise the value of all other items in the group. So in the end we want to end up with groups where the least amount of items' value is affected, especially the ones that have a size big enough to have their own group. We want to avoid having items with vastly different values in the same group, while items that have a size big enough to "have their own group" should preferably be by themselves as they are not going to be affected by this group value (there is no problem adding small-sized items with smaller value to this 1-item-group as long as they cannot be added to a closer value group). An example of this would be if Item 'B' had a size 5. This would mean that the new groups would be {'A', 'B'} and {'C'}, instead of {'A', 'B', 'C'}.

Comment: The K-means algorithm works well and is easy to implement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: @ravenspoint That's a great solution to a different problem. We don't know how many groups to have here, and K-means doesn't limit the total size in a single group.

Comment: "We don't know how many groups to have" Sorry, do not understand this.

Comment: "K-means doesn't limit the total size in a single group" If you want to limit group sizes, then simply split larger groups into parts.

Comment: @ravenspoint And your "simply split larger groups into parts" is exactly the original problem EXCEPT that your original split might have left you with no possible solution fitting the criteria.  This does not look like progress towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are somewhat vague.  For example it isn't clear when it is preferable to throw a small value into a group to keep it close to the minimum size.  Or when it is better to have 2 groups almost exactly the minimum size if it makes a third one a bit bigger.

But the problem is clearly NP complete.  It is a variant on the [multiple subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_subset_sum) problem with lots of subsets.  And therefore even the dynamic programming pseudo-polynomial solutions are not going to work out for you.

So probably not best to try to actually BE optimal, just reasonable.  And the actual bounds you gave are so wide that there almost sure to be many solutions. So for a reasonable running time I would suggest a greedy algorithm.

The general idea is that process items by value and move on to the next group when you have roughly the right size.  Proceeding, as much as possible, from smallest value to largest, breaking ties with largest size to smallest.  With backtracking if you run into a dead end.

Unfortunately you have a problem.  Your problem is that you might need to backtrack not only past adding things to the current group, but also back into what you assigned to another group.  Recursion is great for the first kind of backtrack, but not so much the second.

So instead of the implicit stack of recursion, we're going to have an explicit stack.  Every member of the stack will look like `(choices, choice)` where `choices` is an array, and `choice` is an index of which choice was last looked at.  (-1 if we have not yet processed any choices.)

And `choices` will look like `[(action0, i0), (action1, i1), (action2, i2)]`.  Where `i` is the index of the element of interest, and `action` will be one of:

- `new`: Start a new group at `i`
- `add`: Add element `i` to the last group
- `skip`: Skip past `i` to find another element to add
- `state`: Restore some state when we unwind

By making the greedy choice first in choices we'll try to "find the obvious solution" first.  But since all choices are represented, we will find a solution if there is one to be found.

And now the inside of the key loop looks like:

```
choices, choice = choice_stack.pop()
if -1 < choice:
    unwind choices[choice]
choice += 1
if choice < len(choices):
    choice_stack.append((choices, choice)) # Record we are here.
    do choices[choice] # If new, we save state to choice_stack in the process
    figure out next_choices
    if next_choices:
        choice_stack.append((next_choices, -1))
```

And here is complete running Python.

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self, name, value, size):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.size = size

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


def find_groups (elements, min_size, max_size):
    # Make sure that elements are sorted by value, then size descending.
    elements = list(sorted(elements, key=lambda e: (e.value, -e.size)))

    if 0 == len(elements):
        return [] # Trivial.

    # Set up some state.
    groups = []
    used = set()
    size_remaining = sum((e.size for e in elements))
    size_tail = size_remaining
    # Aim to divide evenly between as many groups as we might make.
    target_size = size_remaining / (size_remaining // min_size)
    min_i = 0
    i = 0
    current_size = 0

    choice_stack = []
    choice_stack.append(
        ([('new', 0)], -1))

    while 0 < len(choice_stack) and min_i < len(elements):
        choices, choice = choice_stack.pop()
        if -1 < choice:
            # Need to undo the last choice taken.
            action, i = choices[choice]
            if action == 'state':
                # We cheat and hide the state in i
                size_remaining, target_size, current_size = i
            elif action == 'new':
                min_i = i
                groups.pop()
            elif action == 'add':
                used.remove(i)
                if i < min_i:
                    min_i = i
                groups[-1].pop()
                current_size -= elements[i].size
                size_remaining += elements[i].size
                size_tail += elements[i].size
            elif action == 'skip':
                size_tail += elements[i].size
            else:
                raise Exception(f"Invalid action {action} while unwinding")


        choice += 1
        if choice < len(choices):
            # Record that we are trying this choice
            choice_stack.append((choices, choice))

            # Actually do it.
            action, i = choices[choice]


            # We need to do special processing for new.
            if action == 'new':
                # Save state for rewind.
                state = [size_remaining, target_size, current_size]
                # Setting 0 here means we will rewind if we hit this.
                choice_stack.append(([('state', state)], 0))

                size_tail = size_remaining

                groups.append([])
                current_size = 0

                # Figure out the target group and feasibility.
                target_count = size_remaining // min_size
                if 0 < target_count:
                    # We fail to get here if the last group is too small.
                    target_size = size_remaining / target_count
                    if max_size < target_size:
                        # We can't process anything.
                        continue

            if action == "new":
                pass # We aren't going to actually do anything.
            elif action == "add":
                used.add(i)
                groups[-1].append(elements[i])
                current_size += elements[i].size
                size_remaining -= elements[i].size
                size_tail -= elements[i].size
                if min_i == i:
                    min_i += 1
                i += 1
            elif action == "skip":
                size_tail -= elements[i].size
                i += 1
            else:
                raise Exception(f"Invalid action {action} in processing element {i}")

            # Skip past any previously used elements.
            while i in used:
                if min_i == i:
                    min_i += 1
                i += 1

            # And now what is our next action?
            next_choices = []
            can_new = (action == 'add' and min_size <= current_size and current_size <= max_size)
            if i == len(elements):
                # Special case.
                if can_new:
                    next_choices = [('new', min_i)]
            else:
                can_add = (current_size + elements[i].size <= max_size and min_size <= current_size + size_tail)
                prefer_add = (current_size + elements[i].size <= target_size)

                if can_new:
                    if prefer_add:
                        next_choices = [('add', i), ('new', min_i)]
                    else:
                        next_choices = [('new', min_i), ('add', i)]
                elif can_add:
                    next_choices = [('add', i)]

                # Skipping creates a value gap so is ALWAYS a last choice.
                can_skip = (action != 'new' and min_size <= current_size + size_tail - elements[i].size)
                if can_skip:
                    next_choices.append(('skip', i))

            if 0 < len(next_choices):
                choice_stack.append((next_choices, -1))

    if 0 == len(groups):
        return None
    else:
        return groups


items = [
    Element('A',    10,    3),
    Element('B',    11,    1),
    Element('C',    10,    7),
    Element('D',    15,   11),
    Element('E',    22,    5),
    Element('F',    20,    7),
    Element('G',    25,    1),
]

print(find_groups(items, 10, 100))
print(find_groups(items, 9, 12))
print(find_groups(items, 9, 11))
```

And you can see in the last two that it tries to be greedy, but if it needs to will backtrack.  And will always find a solution if one exists.  (Though backtracking can take exponentially long.)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I added some more context to the post, as it wouldn't have fitted in a comment, so hopefully, it is a bit less vague (it doesn't change much of the premise, it's more of an explanation). I love the idea of greediness and will try it out :)

Comment: @Phasebook The new problem is a fun dynamic programming challenge.  And it may be possible with those constraints to minimize the excess value*size in reasonable time.  I'd have to think about it for a while.